# Python assigning variables with an OR on assignment, multiple statements in one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I am not super familiar with python, and I am having trouble reading this code. I have never seen this syntax, where there multiple statements are paired together (I think) on one line, separated by commas.

```
        if L1.data < L2.data:
            tail.next, L1 = L1, L1.next
```

Also, I don't understand assignment in python with "or": where is the conditional getting evaluated? See this example. When would tail.next be assigned L1, and when would tail.next be assigned L2?

```
    tail.next = L1 or L2
```

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated. I haven't been able to find much on either syntax

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 1
>>> a, b
(0, 1)
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a, b
(1, 0)
>>>
```

It allows one to swap values without requiring a temporary variable.
In your case, the line

```
tail.next, L1 = L1, L1.next
```

is equivalent to

```
tail.next = L1
L1 = L1.next
```

Answer (score 0):

In python when we write any comma separated values it creates a tuple (a kind of a datastructure).

```
a = 4,5
type(a) --> tuple
```

This is called tuple packing.

When we do:

```
a, b = 4,5
```

This is called tuple unpacking. It is equivalent to:

```
a = 4
b = 5
```

or is the boolean operator here.